# How to install Ragnarok on Ubuntu 22.04.3?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

New to Ubuntu. I wanna try out playing Ragnarok. Is there anyone who has figured out a way to install and play Ragnarok on your PC? Would it be better to install it using Wine/Bottles/Play On Linux?

Comment: Ragnarok is a TV series on Netflix. I know zero games named "Ragnarok". I know a "Ragnarok online" and "Thor Ragnarok" and "God of War: Ragnarok".  If you want to play games on wine find the recipe for that game. We know not a lot about wine. "Would it be better to install it using Wine/Bottles/Play On Linux?" is asking for opinions. Not accepted here. "Is there anyone who has figured out a way to install and play Ragnarok on your PC? " all you want is a yes or no?

Comment: This is Ragnarok Online: https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=701 (version 1, the one using 'fake' 3d; not the one they made in 3d).